# Read files from vintage DOS 3.3 .dsk

Tags: apple2gs

I have a .dsk file, as used by Apple II emulators. It's DOS 3.3 format. How can I get the individual files off it as single files?

Nice would be either an existing tool or documentation of the sector structure of DOS 3.3 (I don't mind writing code, not at all).

(I used tag apple2gs since it already exists, and rep 101 not enough to make new tags.)

Comment: This isn't very much (http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/DSK_(Apple_II)), it it might help in getting details about the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two utilities with source code [here](http://stjarnhimlen.se/apple2/#FID):

- FID - "File Developer" for .DSK images of DOS 3.3 disks

  FID is a file manipulation utility for DOS 3.3 disk images in .DSK format.
- a2tools

  a2tools is a utility similar to FID: it can do a "CATALOG", "DELETE", "SAVE" and "LOAD" on Apple II .DSK images.

a2tools seems at least compilable, but I don't have any .dsk files to test it with.

Comment: A++++ would ask again!

I mean, many thanks, this is just what I was looking for. Compiled & ran ok. Now I get to read carefully the source code to understand disk format better. (Edit for future readers -- I found FID at the site referenced, which worked. a2tools I found at ftp://ftp.apple.asimov.net/pub/apple_II/utility/a2tools-v003.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two popular tools for handling Apple II disk images. They handle all major disk image formats (e.g. DSK, PO, 2IMG, NIB) and file systems (e.g. DOS 3.3, ProDOS, CP/M, Pascal) and can do various disk image or file conversions as well as file extraction.

- [CiderPress](http://a2ciderpress.com/) is a Windows MFC app but it runs fine under Wine on Linux or Mac OS X
- [AppleCommander](http://applecommander.sourceforge.net/) is a Java GUI, command-line utility and library

Answer (score -1):

Google tells me that Disk Utility can mount it, or even DiskImageMounter, if you just double-click it.

Failing that, rename it to .dmg & try again.

I don't have one to test with, so YMMV.

*Edit*
I found one to test - & none of the above was any good :(

This looks like it might be useful - though it looks like it needs more terminal massaging than I'd be any good at - http://apple2online.com/index.php?p=1_73_Using-Downloaded-Software

Comment: I didn't downvote, but FYI the DSK image format is pre-Mac OS so standard Mac tools won't know what to do with it, and the link you give relates to writing a DSK image back to a real floppy. It's a different world! ; - )